# Blending operations in Metal

Tags: metal

When blending with sourceRGBBlendFactor = sourceAlpha which one alpha value will be taken in formula - original source alpha, calculated in shader or alpha value calculated by sourceAlphaBlendFactor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the original source alpha. You can think of these two calculations (`MTLBlendOperationAdd`) as occurring concurrently.

```
RGB = Source.rgb * SBF + Dest.rgb * DBF
A = Source.a * SBF + Dest.a * DBF
```